# Split string using backslash

Tags: c#, string, split

I want to split a string using the backslash ('\'). However, it's not allowed - the compiler says "newline in constant". Is there a way to split using backslash?

```cs
//For example...
String[] breakApart = sentence.Split('\'); //this gives an error.
```

Answer (score 94, accepted):

Try using the escaped character `'\\'` instead of `'\'`:

```cs
String[] breakApart = sentence.Split('\\');
```

The backslash `\` in C# is used as an escape character for special characters like quotes and apostrophes.  So when you are trying to wrap the backslash with apostrophes, the backslash together with the final apostrophe is being interpreted as an escaped apostrophe.

[Here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/csharpfaq/archive/2004/03/12/what-character-escape-sequences-are-available.aspx) is a list of character escapes available in C#.

[Here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/language-specification/lexical-structure#character-literals) is Microsoft's documentation for character literals in C#.

Comment: Make sure also your input string is escaping its content like 'SOMEDOMAIN\\SOMEUSERNAME'' - or else you will get unexpected splitting of your string and hair follicles.

Answer (score 17):

It's backslash, a [character literal](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/language-specification/lexical-structure#character-literals).

To do the split:

```cs
String[] breakApart = sentence.Split('\\');
```

Answer (score 2):

you can use `@`

```
String[] breakApart = sentence.Split(@"\");
```

Comment: This is effectively identical to the well-established accepted answer, except that you're using a different method of escaping the backslash.

Comment: This is the only variation that worked for me