# c# How to split a string using a back slash (double slash not working)

Tags: c#, split, backslash

I'm trying to split a string using the **'\'**.

I've read the topic [How to split using a back slash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16783616/how-to-split-using-a-back-slash), where are a good advice to use the escaped character **'\\'** instead of **'\'** in `Split` method.

However if I'm using **'\\'**, this "eating" the first symbols of my words I want to split.

Here my code:

```
        string firstString = "one\two\three";
        char a = '\\';
        string[] splittedString = firstString.Split(a);
        foreach (string s in splittedString)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(s);
        }
```

**//Output is "one   wo   hree"**

So WHY? Where is my mistake?

Comment: `\t` expands to a tab character. Did you mean `"one\\two\\three"` (or `@"one\two\three"`)?

Comment: Backslash isn't working because `"one\two\three"` does not have backslashes. Change to `@"one\two\three"`, and run your program again.

Comment: It is working perfectly. You should read an explanation on escape characters again. As mentioned above, there are no backslashes in the `firstString`.

Comment: @spender my string was excatly with one slashes like "one\two\three". And yes both variants "one\\two\\three" or @"one\two\three" correct my code. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You either need to escape the \ in firstString like this

```
string firstString = "one\\two\\three";
```

Or prefix it with an "@" like this

```
string firstString = @"one\two\three";
```

These might help https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/csharpfaq/2004/03/12/what-character-escape-sequences-are-available/ and http://www.yoda.arachsys.com/csharp/strings.html

Answer (score 1):

Try to rewrite

```
string firstString = "one\\two\\three";
```